# How to move web apps over subscription

Tags: azureportal

Is that possible to move app/resources from one subscription to another?

Assume, I have access to "Subscription A" and "Subscription B" and I have a web app "app 1" in "Subscription A" which is in live production. Now I want to move "app 1" from "Subscription A" to "Subscription B" without any changes.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but there can be caveats depending on the resource and some resources cannot be moved. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources). The explanation of how to do it in the portal is towards the bottom of the page.